# Unable to .append(); without eliminating all the spaces in the code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
$('#form_holder').append('<div id="spec_id_'+count+'"><div class="avail_container">

<input class="avail_fields" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="special'+count+'" /><span class="avail_field_label">Special Date</span></div>
<div class="avail_container"><div class="avail_time_container"><span class="field_label">Time</span>
    <select name="special'+count+'_time_from_1">

    <?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<24; $t++){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $t; ?>"><?php echo $t; ?></option>

        <?php
        }

        ?>
    </select>:
    <select name="special'+count+'_time_from_2">
            <?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<60; $t+=15){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?>"><?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?></option>

        <?php
        }

        ?>
    </select>

    <span class="field_label">to</span>
    <select name="special'+count+'_time_to_1">
        <?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<24; $t++){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $t; ?>"><?php echo $t; ?></option>

        <?php
        }

        ?>
    </select>:
    <select name="special'+count+'_time_to_2">
                    <?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<60; $t+=15){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?>"><?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?></option>

        <?php
        }

        ?>
    </select>

    </div>
</div>
</div>');
```

I'm assuming javascript or jquery does not like breaks like I have here, because all my javascript code does not work.

What would be an alternative to eliminating all the spaces, which would make viewing the code difficult?

Comment: You are mixing php and js.. Can you verify?

Comment: yes I am. can I not do that? Is that bad practice? I am reusing the code that is used to do the initial html. Basically the php is used to build the html that will be appended.

Comment: Well in terms of maintenance it would be a nightmare..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this not checked

```
var varVal1=<?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<24; $t++){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $t; ?>"><?php echo $t; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>;
var varVal2=<?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<60; $t+=15){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?>"><?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
var varVal3=<?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<24; $t++){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $t; ?>"><?php echo $t; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
var varVal4=<?php
        for ($t = 0; $t<60; $t+=15){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?>"><?php if($t == 0){ echo $t . '' . $t; }else{ echo $t; } ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
$('#form_holder').append('<div id="spec_id_'+count+'">'+
    '<div class="avail_container">'+
    '<input class="avail_fields" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="special'+count+'" />'+
    '<span class="avail_field_label">Special Date</span>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="avail_container">'+
    '<div class="avail_time_container">'+
    '<span class="field_label">Time</span>'+
    '<select name="special'+count+'_time_from_1">'+varVal1+
    '</select>:'+
    '<select name="special'+count+'_time_from_2">'+varVal2+
    '</select>'+
    '<span class="field_label">to</span>'+
    '<select name="special'+count+'_time_to_1">'+varVal3+
    '</select>:'+
    '<select name="special'+count+'_time_to_2">'+varVal4+             
    '</select>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>');
```

with regards

**Wazzy**

Comment: yep. but I had to treat the vars as if they were strings by using echo. Not pretty, however I needed a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape the line breaks.

```
var str = 'this is a string\
           on multiple lines\
           with the line breaks escaped.'
```

or concatenate the string.

```
var str = 'this is a string' +
          'on multiple lines' +
          'with the line breaks escaped.'
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, first, to allow a javascript string to span multiple lines end every line with a backslash

etc...

```
var string = 'This is a javascript\
              string that spans\
              multiple lines';
```

Second, PHP code cannot be rendered in javascript so your  code will be simply displayed and not processed like you are wanting it to be.

I would recommend using ajax to go out and grab the html you want to be appended so the php is processed.